# Discerning how much one should trust Hashem

Tags: mussar-ethics, faith-bitachon-emunah

Shalom.

I am far from being a Ba’al Bitachon, but from what I have read - e.g. this: https://www.torah-box.net/jewish-ethics-and-learning/jewish-thinking/emunah-and-bitachon-two-essential-tools_572.html - it seems that man must decide for himself how much he should trust Hashem, and how much to work for his / the community’s salvation.

That said: Are there any guidelines available that would help someone decide how much to trust, and how much hishtadlus to do? Is this a simple matter of weighing one’s deeds / aveirot against particular historical persons whose fate we know about and deciding (how much to trust) on that basis?

Also, a related question: Does deciding how much one should trust Hashem mean making an assessment about how much good one should expect to come to one / one’s loved ones in the future?

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a complex topic.  I suggest that you get hold of a copy of Rabbi Asher Weiss on Emunah and Bitachon where he deals with issues like this.